# Faster FFMPEG conversion from WMV

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm converting a lot of WMV files to MP4.

The command is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 0 -y -i source.wmv destination.mp4
```

I have roughly 100gb to convert. 24 hours later it's still not done (xeon, 64gb, super fast storage)

Am I missing something out? is there a better way to convert?

Comment: Use a faster [x264 encoding preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapreset).

Comment: I didn't even know there was such a thing! thanks!

Comment: Answer added. If you show the complete console output from your ffmpeg command I may be able to come up with more suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a list of various things you can try:

## Preset

Use a faster [x264 encoding preset](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#a2.Chooseapreset). A preset is a set of options that gives a speed vs compression efficiency tradeoff. Current presets in descending order of speed are: ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium, slow, slower, veryslow, placebo. The default preset is "medium". Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -preset fast output.mp4
```

## CPU capabilities

Check that the encoder is actually using the capabilities of your CPU. When encoding via libx264 the console output should show something like:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7f8451001e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
```

If it shows `none` then encoding speed will suffer. Your x264 is likely misconfigured and you'll need to get a new one or re-compile.

## ASM

Related to the above suggestion, but make sure your ffmpeg was not configured with `--disable-asm`, `--disable-inline-asm`, and/or `--disable-yasm`.

Also, make sure your x264 that is linked to ffmpeg is not compiled with `--disable-asm`.

If these configure options are used then encoding will be much slower.

## AAC

You can encode AAC audio faster using the `-aac_coder fast` option when using the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`). However, this will have much less of an impact than choosing a faster preset for H.264 video encoding, and the audio quality will probably be reduced when compared to omitting `-aac_coder fast`.

## ffmpeg

Use a recent ffmpeg. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, macOS, and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In my case simple `WMV` to `MP4` conversion using this command `ffmpeg -i input.wmv output.mp4` increased size of file from **5.7MB** to **350MB** and the speed was 0.190x, which took ages to make mp4 video. Anyway, I waited more than 2 hours for it to finish and found out, that output video had 1000 frames/second. Having in mind, that it was Full HD video, 2 hours were pretty okay. My solution looks like this

`ffmpeg -i input.wmv -crf 26 -vf scale=iw/3:ih/3,fps=15 output.mp4`

Here I reduce video height and width in 3 times, make it only 15 fps and make a little compression

which resulted in:

- only 5.7MB -> **15MB**
- **278x** speed improvement! (from 0.19x to **52.9x**)
- some quality loss, but for me it was not so neccessary